# How to check for transform array items null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The lookObjects array have two places in the inspector but they are empty.
In the code the array lookObjects is not null and it's length is more then 0 but because the two places in the inspector are empty i'm getting exception.

[image: Null]

The exception is on line 34 :

```
Vector3 lookAt = target.position - transform.position;
```

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable lookObj of IKTests has not been assigned.

In case i forgot in the inspector some items empty how should i handle it in the code ?

could be one empty item in the array and some other not empty. or maybe i forgot to assign them all.

Comment: It's not an empty item in `lookObj`, the `lookObj` itself is not assigned aka null. I guess it's public? If you click the exception, the problem-causing object is selected - I suppose you have more than one object using the error-throwing script and in one of them you didn't assign the `lookObj`. Maybe search the hierarchy using `t:YourScriptType` to find all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the lookObj that are not null then you can check target == null then continue, or another option is to remove all null objects from the list of lookObj:
var lookObj = lookObj.RemoveAll(l=>l == null)